# "UserWarning: Duplicate name"- when trying to make .exe with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert a python script to executable

### Setup:

- Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
- WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5 (Python 3.5.2 64-bit
- cx_Freeze v. 4.3.4 (came with winPython)

### File to be converted as exe:

matplotlib_eg.py (an example file), from `WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib`.

### Setup.py

(The original setup.py file with added os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] and os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] lines)

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\tcl\tcl8.6" 
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\tcl\tk8.6" 


base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'excludes': ['Tkinter']  # Sometimes a little finetuning is needed
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('matplotlib_eg.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='matplotlib_eg',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample matplotlib script',
      executables=executables,
      options=options
      )
```

### Problem

I get the following errors when running `python setup.py build`:

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py:590: UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'importlib/__init__.pyc'
  outFile.writestr(zinfo, data)
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py:590: UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'statsmodels/__init__.pyc'
  outFile.writestr(zinfo, data)
```

Any ideas how to fix the "Duplicate name"-warning/error? It makes an executable but the executable does not do anything when ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use cx_Freeze 5.0 which supports Python 3.5 and was just released last week. The matplotlib example has been updated and confirmed to work in that release.

Comment: No errors during build with cx_Freeze 5.0, but I did not get the example working since it is using wxPython (but that would be a topic of a new question).